# SmartGWT together with UIBinder

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder

Now I have a project on GWT with UIBinder and I need to integrate SmartGWT into it. If I'm just trying to add SmartGWT components to ui.xml and view class as plain GWT components, I get an error when compiling. What additional actions should I make for using the SmartGWT widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartGWT doesn't provide UiBinder support. But you can use **uibinding-smartgwt**. A project to adapt SmartGWT for UiBinder.

Then just add `xmlns:zs="urn:import:org.synthful.smartgwt.client.widgets"` on your UiBind xml.

More info [here](http://code.google.com/p/uibinding-smartgwt/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I can not compile the project with SmartGWT and uibinding-smartgwt:( I added the Maven dependency for SmartGWT and uibinding-smartgwt. I also added this string to my ui.xml and and I tried to add SmartGWT widgets declaring them in a ui.xml file and view class, as I do with plain GWT widgets. But when I tried to compile the project, I get error in the view class: "No source code is available for type org.synthful.smartgwt.client.widgets.UIHLayout; did you forget to inherit a required module?" Do you have any ideas?

Comment: A class to be used as a parent node of GWT Widgets must implement HasWidget, and any class that are its candidate child nodes must be extension classes of GWT Widget. A class to be used as parent node of HTML contents must implement HasHTML. A class to be used as a node for encapsulating text content must implement HasText.

Make sure your Widget follow those specifications, maybe, some SmartGWT Widget's aren't supported yet. Try to add the example Widget of wiki page project 
http://code.google.com/p/uibinding-smartgwt/wiki/UsingUITabSet

Comment: I have been busy using GXT for the past 18 months. I will induct anyone seriously wanting to contribute to the project. Please write to gmail id: blessedgeek. In the past I have removed contributors/owners who seems to only want their name associated with the project without contributing anything.